# WearableActionDrawer peek view does not hide

Tags: wear-os

I'm trying to use WearableActionDrawer in my app.  Previously I was using 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0-alpha1' and my layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_activity_main"
    app:roundLayout="@layout/round_activity_main"
    tools:context="com.example.grant.wearableclimbtracker.MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id = "@+id/content_frame">
        <android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableNavigationDrawer
        android:id = "@+id/top_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_grey"/>

    <android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableActionDrawer
        android:id="@+id/bottom_action_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey" />
</android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout>
```

After I switched to 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0' the behavior changed.  The action drawer used to stay out of view until I swiped up to reveal the action menu, but now there is a peek view of the drawer that doesn't go away unless I open the menu and select something.  Is this the intended behavior?  It takes up a lot of real-estate:

[image]

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this [blog](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sneak-peek-latest-android-wear-features-while-developing-abi-jones) about the Wearable Drawers Enhancement. It stated that it shows the first action in `WearableActionDrawer`’s peek view. For additional customization in the wearable drawers, `peek_view` and `drawer_content` attributes have been added to `WearableDrawerView`. The navigation drawer contents can be updated by calling notifyDataSetChanged. You may also check this [related thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidPreviews/comments/4hcfin/how_to_disable_peekheads_up_notifications_on/).

Comment: @abielita I've looked at both links but doesn't seem to answer my question.  From the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/ui-nav-actions.html): 

_By default, the action drawer will peek when the user reaches the top
or bottom of the main scrolling content (that is, the view that
implements NestedScrollingChild)._

I think the problem might be that the content in NestedScrollingChild matches the parent, so maybe android thinks it has reached the top/bottom of the scrollview?  Is there any way to change this behavior to hide the peek view by default?

Comment: Are you maybe calling peekDrawer in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was as I suspected, when NestedScrollingChild height matched the parentview, the action drawer peeks.  The only way I could get it to hide was to increase the NestedScrollingChild view by 1dp:

```
// get the screen width
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

// set height of framelayout to be slightly larger than view
mSessionLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sessionLayout);
mSessionLayout.setMinimumHeight(metrics.heightPixels+1);
```

Comment: Thank you, it is dirty, but it works. I did it by extending the layout, and overriding `onMeasure` as follows 
`
    @Override
         protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size+1, mode);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
`